# irssi cannot connect to IRC servers (cygwin)

Tags: cygwin, irssi

I would like to be a more active user of IRSSI as I am not a big fan of either Pidgin, XChat or mIRC, having used all of them for over a year.

Unfortunately Irssi seems to be unable to connect to IRC. There has been no problem in connecting to http, ftp via command-line in cygwin. I have configured dmz to this computer, but it made no difference.

I have also tried connecting via SSL and trying alternative Freenode servers. I cannot connect to Quakenet and EFNet either, so I assume I cannot connect to any IRC server.

```
16:15 -!- Irssi: Looking up irc.freenode.net
16:15 -!- Irssi: Connecting to irc.freenode.net [216.155.130.130] port 6667
16:15 -!- Irssi: Connection to irc.freenode.net established
16:15 !verne.freenode.net *** Looking up your hostname...
16:15 !verne.freenode.net *** Checking Ident
16:15 !verne.freenode.net *** Found your hostname
16:15 !verne.freenode.net *** No Ident response
16:15 -!- ERROR Closing Link: my.hostname.net (Connection timed out)
16:15 -!- Irssi: Connection lost to irc.freenode.net
```

Comment: Is the problem still valid ?

Comment: No, this issue was ages ago.